# PLT Scheme - Tracking environment variable bindings

Tags: variables, binding, scheme, environment, racket

I am attempting to create a simple language interpreter for a homework assignment in PLT Scheme (Racket). For tracking variable bindings, I cannot seem to create and update an environment that tracks assigned variables and their values. In the MIT Scheme Reference, I found information about environments being first class objects, but using the commands listed there (such as **environment-bound?**) do not work in PLT Scheme.

What is the best way to accomplish this is scheme without using **let** or any imperative-like (**!**) functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just creating an interpreter in Scheme, you might want to just create your own environment data structure, possibly as an association list: `((var1 val1) (var2 val2) (var3 val3))` and so on.  It's simpler to pass around and update the environment as a list, rather than dealing with any particular Scheme's implementation of environments.

Comment: I finished the problem earlier today, and this is the solution I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

Look up in the docs for anything around [namespace functionality](http://docs.racket-lang.org/search/index.html?q=namespace).

Comment: I appreciate the link as it will no doubt help me in the future. However, any call to namespace related procedures also result in PLT Scheme erroring with 'reference to undefined identifier: [procedure name]'

Comment: Obviously, creating your own interpreter is very different than using Racket namespaces!  You'd want to use any data structure that fits the job like the alists that were mentioned above or hash tables, or any number of other solutions.  You'd use namespaces when you want to do reflective jobs -- like defining a new language *based* on Racket (which happens to be a language that makes this very easy).